# Typescript Indentation in org-babel (ob-typescript)

Tags: org-babel

I've setup org-babel for Typescript and the indentation is all over the place. What exactly controls this indentation?;)

I basically just have this code in my configuration:

```
(defun org-babel-execute:typescript (body params)                                                                                                                                                                                             
  (org-babel-execute:js                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
   (with-temp-buffer                                                                                                                                                                                                                          
     (let* ((ts-file (concat (temporary-file-directory) (make-temp-name "script") ".ts"))                                                                                                                                                     
            (js-file (replace-regexp-in-string ".ts$" ".js" ts-file)))                                                                                                                                                                        
       (insert body)                                                                                                                                                                                                                          
       (write-region nil nil ts-file)                                                                                                                                                                                                         
       (call-process-shell-command (concat "npx tsc " (shell-quote-argument ts-file)))                                                                                                                                                        
       (delete-region (point-min) (point-max))                                                                                                                                                                                                
       (insert-file js-file)                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
       (let ((js-source (buffer-substring (point-min) (point-max))))                                                                                                                                                                          
         (delete-file ts-file)                                                                                                                                                                                                                
         (delete-file js-file)                                                                                                                                                                                                                
         js-source)))                                                                                                                                                                                                                         
   params)) 

(setq org-src-tab-acts-natively t)                                                                                                                                                                                                            
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              
;; org-mode evaluate typescript and Maxima blocks without confirmation                                                                                                                                                                        
(defun ck/org-confirm-babel-evaluate (lang body)                                                                                                                                                                                              
  (not (or (string= lang "typescript") (string= lang "maxima"))))                                                                                                                                                                             
(setq org-confirm-babel-evaluate 'ck/org-confirm-babel-evaluate) 

;;typescript-mode ansi colors for compilation mode                                                                                                                                                                                            
(require 'ansi-color)                                                                                                                                                                                                                         
(defun colorize-compilation-buffer ()                                                                                                                                                                                                         
  (ansi-color-apply-on-region compilation-filter-start (point-max)))                                                                                                                                                                          
(add-hook 'compilation-filter-hook 'colorize-compilation-buffer)
```

Comment: IME, `C-c '` is your friend: it gets you a buffer in the appropriate mode which deals well with indentation and `C-c C-'` copies it back properly indented. Trying to indent in the code block is a crap shoot IMO.

Comment: indeed, thanks;), but why is the indentation in the ob-typescript code block such a crap shoot? Is this only for Typescript or for all org-babel code block languages?

Comment: I don't know. I've noticed it and keep meaning to investigate but never seem to find the time. I've noticed it with other languages (lisp in particular) - I don't use Typescript.